# OpenVPN: How to issue client IP on the same subnet as the server LAN

Tags: vpn, routing, openvpn

Is it possible to issue a client an IP address on the same subnet as the server LAN?  For example, if the server's IP address is `10.50.1.5`, I would like to assign the connecting clients an IP on the same subnet.  Something like `10.50.1.200`.  I'm hoping this will help with routing as I have a need to connect to an internal system (`10.50.1.20`) that is having trouble routing packets back to the connected VPN client machine.

My current conf:

```
dev tun
proto tcp
port 443
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/issued/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/private/key.key
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
topology subnet
server 10.50.1.248 255.255.255.248
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
# Prevent DNS leaks on Windows
push "block-outside-dns"
push "redirect-gateway def1"
client-to-client
keepalive 15 120
remote-cert-tls client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-crypt /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ta.key
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
user openvpn
group openvpn
persist-key
persist-tun
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/crl.pem
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log 20
status-version 3
syslog
verb 3
```

Once connected, I'm being issued an IP of 10.50.1.250 which is what I would expect but I'm not able to ping 10.50.1.1 or access the internet.

When I had the server configured with a `server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0` and an iptables NAT route like

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

that worked, but I was still having a routing issue from an internal system back to the client.  Again, was hoping that could be resolved by placing the client on the same subnet as the internal systems.

UPDATE 2020-05-19 12:21 PT:

I added a NAT route on the OpenVPN server of:

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.50.1.248/29 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

After doing so, I was able to ping the address `10.50.1.20` (and get to the internet) but I'm still having issues with the response from that system.  When I traceroute from my client to `10.50.1.20` it routes through `10.50.1.249` which seems correct so it appears the issue is with the route back from `10.50.1.20 (system) > 10.50.1.250 (VPN client)`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Configure as TAP [layer 2], not TUN [layer 3], to accomplish this. _FYIs about your server config:_ **(1)** AES128 will remain uncrackable through at least 2030; all you're doing by using `cipher aes-256-cbc` is drastically slowing throughput to a crawl with zero security gained; **(2)** At minimum, `dh dh2048.pem` should be used; **(3)** If the clients use x64 CPUs, `auth sha512` should be used, as x64 CPUs process SHA512 faster than SHA256; **(4)** There's only _two_ use cases for `proto tcp`: high packet loss with `proto udp` or troubleshooting, as TCP cannot efficiently encapsulate itself.

Answer (score 1):

"Same subnet" implies that the address will be reachable at MAC level. But that's never true when there is a router in between (your VPN server is the router).

You can still make this work, by making the server *itself* respond to ARP requests for these addresses. That way when other LAN hosts attempt to reach the client, they'll end up using the VPN server's MAC address.

- Proxy individual addresses: `ip neigh add proxy 10.50.1.250 dev eth0`
- Proxy CIDR ranges: Install the [parpd](https://github.com/rsmarples/parpd) daemon.
- Proxy everything that's routed not via eth0: `sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eth0.proxy_arp=1` (probably not recommended)

When doing this, remove all your NAT or MASQUERADE rules – there should never be any NAT between local networks and especially between halves of the same subnet, except as a last resort.

---

There is an alternative method – actual Ethernet *bridging*. If you add `dev-mode tap` to your OpenVPN configuration, it will create fully Ethernet-compatible 'tap' interfaces instead of the usual IP-only 'tun'. Then you can just bridge the 'tap0' and 'eth0' interfaces into a single subnet.

The downside of this alternative method is that 'tap' mode is not compatible with mobile clients (Android or iOS), and possibly incompatible with macOS as well.

Comment: Do you by chance know the reason for the lack of support for TAP on mobile devices? Is it due to permission issues, cell providers assigning devices RFC1918 subnets _(seems like this would be the most problematic)_, or that cellular radios don't conform to RFC rules _(or none of those)_?

Comment: It's definitely unrelated to cell networks or cell providers. TAP interfaces are virtual and completely independent of any physical network; their "other end" simply goes into the OpenVPN daemon (the same way as with TUN). It is entirely the mobile OS developers' choice that they provide an official API for writing apps for layer-3 (Tun) VPNs, but do not provide one for layer-2 ones.

Comment: Although now that you mention it, I guess it doesn't forever prevent such VPNs from working -- it just requires the VPN app to add/strip the Ethernet header and handle ARP/NDP all by itself, instead of the OS doing it. Which is certainly a bit of extra work, but I'm sure I've seen at least one app doing exactly that (zerotier)...